# Trigger function and trigger to change one column after an update

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm new to psql and triggers. I am trying to create a trigger function and a trigger such that on an update of a single column the value of that column for the rest of table should be updated. Here is an example

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text | true |
| 2 | text | false |
| 3 | text | false |
| 4 | text | false |
| 5 | text | false |

With the table above, assume that there is an update to the first row, where the value of col2 has been set to `true`. I want to create a trigger function and trigger such that when there is an another update on the table, for example we set `col2` for `id=3` to `true`, the value of `col2` for `id=1` should be set to `false`.

Basically, what I want the trigger to do is to ensure that only one row in the entire table can have `col2` set as `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_set_false()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
BEGIN

if new.col2 = true then 
update test_table set col2 = false where col2 = true and id != new.id;
end if;

return new;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

and call it in trigger (before update)

```
CREATE  TRIGGER "test_set_false_update_trigger" BEFORE update ON test_table
                FOR EACH ROW
                EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_set_false();
```